# Compiling C++ Paho MQTT code gives error "Could not find Paho MQTT C library"

Tags: c++, cmake, mqtt, paho, pahocpp

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, I cloned the c library at `~/Paho_MQTT/paho_c` and ran following commands in `paho.mqtt.c` folder,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make cmake cmake-gui cmake-curses-gui
sudo apt-get install fakeroot fakeroot devscripts dh-make lsb-release
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install doxygen graphviz
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

All goes well.

Then I cloned c++ code at `~/Paho_MQTT/paho_cpp`, and ran following commands in the `paho.mqtt.cpp` folder,

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DPAHO_MQTT_C_PATH=~/Paho_MQTT/paho_c/paho.mqtt.c ..
```

Here I get error, "Could not find Paho MQTT C library",
Can you please suggest any solution ?

Comment: Unsure whether CMake is able to resolve `~` path in variables. Instead, use literal `/home/<user-name>`.

Comment: tried it, but still same error,

Comment: make sure you have updated cmake and git repo cloned in proper state

Comment: I'm setting up the environment for development on a new machine so all the software is latest, also the repo is cloned properly, I tried to clone the repos in two different directories, but get same error